# How do I send .png plot to stdout in gnuplot?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Currently, I do something like the following:

```
set term png
set output 'file.png'
```

But hardcoding filename in the script is quite inflexible. Is there some way to tell gnuplot to output image file to stdout, so I will be able to redirect it's output where needed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do want to send your .png to stdout, just don't set the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set term png
plot x
```

Then run the script

```
./plot.plt > mypng.png
```

I think the bash wrapper makes more sense for most purposes, but this is potentially useful as well.

Comment: I, on the other hand, believe that bash wrapper is almost useless for most purposes. This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: For other people who might hit the same snag as me and are seeing `gnuplot> ` in their output: don't run `gnuplot -` when giving commands on stdin, just pipe to `gnuplot` without `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your gnuplot script inside a script and use a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF
set term png
set output "$1.png"
plot "$1.dat"
EOF
```

Now invoke the script, say `plot.sh`, by specifying the prefix to output file and data as argument: `bash plot.sh file`.